# Correctly using --shard in GNU parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I'd like to use the `--shard` flag in GNU parallel to do some concurrency control.

My input file (`input.csv`) looks like this:

```
node-foo,op1
node-bar,op2
node-baz,op3
node-foo,op4
node-blah,op5
...
```

I'm using `parallel` to send ops to nodes. Node names may appear more than once in the first column. I'd like to use `--shard` to ensure that at most one op is sent to a node at a time.

My command looks something like this:
`parallel --shard 1 send_op.sh --node={1} --op={2} ::: input.csv`

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. `parallel` tells me "`--shard` requires `--jobs` to be higher than the number of arguments. Increase `--jobs`."

This doesn't make sense to me. Doesn't it defeat the point of `--shard` if `--jobs` is set to be higher than the number of input lines (the number of ops in my example)? How can I achieve my desired concurrency property?

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to use --shard to ensure that at most one op is sent to a node at a time.

This is not what `--shard` does. `--shard` is a specialized version of `--pipe`, and you are not using pipe-mode.

So what can you do instead?

`sem` makes sure only a single jobs with that id runs in parallel. So you might be able to:

```
parallel --colsep , sem --id {1} send_op.sh --node={1} --op={2} :::: input.csv
```

This solution has some issues:

- Order matters - a lot. If all node-A are grouped together, these will take up jobslots in parallel and thus slow down the processing. But if you add `--shuf` to `parallel` the order will be shuffled and thus this would be less of an issue.
- `sem` takes 150 ms to start. So if your jobs are short lived (< 1 s total wall clock time) you may see this as slowing down your processing.